# Only trigger if specific table class is avaible

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Ok i have this coffescript in my rails app:

```
onEndless = ->
  $(window).off 'scroll', onEndless
  url = $('.paginator .next a').attr('href')
  $('.paginator').hide()
  if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 150
    $('.loader').show()
    $.getScript url, ->
      $(window).on 'scroll', onEndless
  else
    $(window).on 'scroll', onEndless

$(window).on 'scroll', onEndless

$(window).scroll()
```

My problem at the time is that it gets triggered on several sites so i thought i could add a specific id to a table `id="imagedocus_table"` that is only on this site, and let only trigger the code if this id is avaible! But how? Thanks!

My html:

```
...... 
 <table class="table" id="imagedocus_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="50px"></th>
          .......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do a

```
return unless $('#imagedocus_table').length
```

before your code